# Error with Display() function in EBImage

Tags: rstudio

I use the package EBImage from RStudio but i've got this error when i execute the display function. Try the example function

```
try({
im = readImage("http://www-huber.embl.de/EBImage/ExampleImages/berlin.tif")
display(x =im, title = "Berlin Impressions")
})
```

Erreur dans (function ()  : 
  tentative d'appliquer un objet qui n'est pas une fonction

Translate message -> Error in (function ()  : 
  try to apply an object that isn't a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to RStudio version 0.98.1103